# Google maps on desktop doesn't let me navigate from my current position

Tags: google-maps

When I use Google maps on my phone, it automatically suggests to navigate from my current location. For some reason, I can never find the option on the desktop version of the site.

It doesn't even give me the option to navigate from my house. The only option it gives me is to navigate from my work place (which, I work from home, but it won't let me register my house as my workplace because it's already registered as my home).

Is there anyway to tell Google maps to automatically navigate from my current location or at least my house, instead of having to type in my address or find it on the map *every single time I look up directions to go anywhere?*

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Google Maps in desktop browser used to show my current location (from my Android phone), but this feature disappeared after I got a new phone and it seems I can not enable it anywhere.